# HTML Request in Typescript repository

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I am using Functions in Foundry and using for this purpose Typescript. I am wondering if it is possible to make a HTML Request inside a specific function.

I have already checked every HTML request method I know for JS (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/). However, these methods are not available in a Typescript repo.

Looking on the internet I found a library called conjure-typescript-runtime (https://github.com/palantir/conjure-typescript-runtime) which I think could help. This was developed by Palantir. This library is already installed in Foundry and could be used in Typescript but I cannot find any example on how to do a PUT request using it.

Looking forward to hearing from you and getting some help.

Best,
Pablo

Comment: +1 to what Logan replied. The executor for the TS/JS logic that you write is isolated in a lambda/functions executor, which doesn't necessarily have internet access since by design it only needs to communicate with specific foundry services. What is it that you're trying to write/build here?

Answer (score 0):

While Typescript as a language certainly supports making arbitrary network requests, the execution of Typescript within the Foundry Functions architecture does not allow connections outside of the Foundry enclave and the connections that are allowed are moderated through custom APIs like the Ontology API or the User API rather than arbitrary direct connections.

Comment: Does it mean that connections to other Foundry APIs like Carbon are not possible at the moment?